# Dagger hilt injecting into activity results in UninitializedPropertyAccessException error

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I am trying to inject a class into an activity using dagger hilt using a Module.  I've looked through tutorials and countless SO posts.  I cannot tell what I'm doing wrong.

I have a DataStoreManger class that i'm trying to use in an activity.

```
class DataStoreManager (@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) {...}
```

I have an AppModule that provides a DataStoreManager.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
   @Provides
   @Singleton
   fun provideDataStoreManager(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): 
      DataStoreManager = DataStoreManager(appContext)
}
```

Then I'm trying to use DataStoreManager in MainActivity.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   @Inject lateinit var dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager

   private val userPreferencesFlow = dataStoreManager.userPreferencesFlow
}
```

This results in an uninitialized property access exception

```
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property 
     dataStoreManager has not been initialized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
@Inject lateinit var dataStoreManager
```

The `dataStoreManager` is only actually injected during the call to `super.onCreate()`.

However, when you create a property such as

```
private val userPreferencesFlow = dataStoreManager.userPreferencesFlow
```

This property is created immediately as part of the construction of your `MainActivity` class - it doesn't wait until `onCreate()` runs, hence the error you are receiving.

Generally, the easiest way to avoid this is by only access the `userPreferencesFlow` from your injected manager when you actually want to collect it, which is presumably after `super.onCreate()`.

However, if you want to still create your flow as a member variable at the activity level, you can use `by lazy`:

```
private val userPreferencesFlow by lazy {
    dataStoreManager.userPreferencesFlow
}
```

The `lazy` block will only be executed lazily - e.g., the first time you actually use the member variable, thus ensuring that your `@Inject` variable has actually been injected.